# What is the meaning of the definitions for the "some" and "many" functions in the Haskell Alternative

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, some-and-many

I've been looking to write a lexer in Haskell and stumbled upon these functions.

> If defined, `some` and `many` should be the least solutions of the
>   equations:
>
> `some v = (:) <$> v <*> many v`
>
> `many v = some v <|> pure []`

I get that the `(:)` in `some` gets lifted and applied to the value of `v` in order to prepend it to the list returned in `many v`.

But why does the definition of `many` start with `some`? And why does it get concatenated with `pure []`?

What is the relationship or difference between these two functions? What does it mean for `some` and `many` to be the ***least*** solutions of those equations? And how does the recursion ever stop? Help!

Comment: It doesn't get *concatenated* with `pure []`. The empty list is the *alternative* where the recursion stops.

Comment: `some` means "at least one" while `many` means "none or more".

Comment: Aha thank you. I think this is starting to make sense. So the some guarantees at least one value, followed by 0 or more, and many gives you at least one value (plus 0 or more) *or* nothing. But how exactly does the recursion end? How do values from v get consumed?

Comment: Values from `v` do not get consumed. `some` and `many` are producing a (in a sense) 'larger' value than their input. Recursion ends only if `<*>` and `<|>` are sufficiently lazy. This isn't the case for `[]` or `Maybe`, but it is the case for `IO`. e.g., `many (getLine >>= \x -> if all isDigit x then return x else empty)` will read lines until you enter something containing a non-digit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- `some p` means **one** or more match of p
- `many p` means **zero** or more more match of p

For input `"abc"`, `many letter` and `some letter` will both parse `abc`.

But for input `"123"`, `many letter` will output empty string `""`. `some letter` will report error.

According to the definition. `some v` needs at least 1 match of `v`, so we can first parse `v` then we need 0 or more match of `v`, which is `many v`. It is something like :

```
some v = do
    first_match <- v
    rest_matches <- many v
    return $ first_match : rest_matches
```

which is the same as `some v = (:) <$> v <*> many v`.

But for `many v`. It will either match `some v` (1 or more) or nothing (pure []).

`many v = if matches (some v) then return (some v) else return nothing`.

You can try solve [writing applicative parsers from scratch](https://www.codewars.com/kata/writing-applicative-parsers-from-scratch) from codewars.

[Functional pearls](http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf) is also a very good reference about parse combinators.

---

1. https://www.codewars.com/kata/writing-applicative-parsers-from-scratch
2. http://www.cs.nott.ac.uk/~pszgmh/pearl.pdf